# linked server: four prefixes work with select but not alter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Server 13.0 box with
[EC2AMAZ\SQLEXPRESS] as a linked server

I'm running the following commands on the SQL Server 13.0 box
and this select statements work just fine:

```
select * from [EC2AMAZ\SQLEXPRESS].[import].[dbo].[table]
```

but this:

```
ALTER TABLE [EC2AMAZ\SQLEXPRESS].[import].[dbo].[table] ADD field
nvarchar(4000)
```

throws the error:

> The object name 'EC2AMAZ\SQLEXPRESS.import.dbo.table' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near 'field'.

why is it okay to use four prefixes for select but not alter?

Comment: You'll notice that the allowed amount is **2**, so cross database statements aren't even allowed, let alone cross server. In truth, the linked server is irrelevant

Comment: Because making schema DDL modifications is not supported cross-server or via linked servers.

Comment: @Larnu I think stu has the correct answer because the select statement works fine with 4

Comment: You missed the point of my comment entirely, @user713813 . You can't `ALTER` a table in another **database**; you can't even use 3 part naming, so it's unsurprising that 4 part isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run DDL against a linked server. One workaround is to use dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC [EC2AMAZ\SQLEXPRESS].[import].sys.sp_executesql 
  N'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] ADD field nvarchar(4000);';
```

The syntax diagram in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) does *not* include four-part names for `ALTER TABLE`:

> [image: ALTER TABLE syntax diagram]

It is officially documented (albeit indirectly) for `SELECT` in the docs for [`FROM {<table_source>}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql):

> If the table or view exists outside the instance of SQL Serverl, use a four-part name in the form *linked_server.catalog.schema.object*.

(Typo is free!)

Such reference does not exist for `ALTER TABLE`. Yes, it kind of sucks that we have to infer from *lack* of documentation that something isn't possible, but imagine even trying to document all of the things a feature *can't do*?

> **This car**:
> - cannot be used as a flotation device
> - is not a sufficient source of vitamin C
> - cannot vote
> - may not respond to "Betsy"
> - does not fly
> - will not fit into bell-bottoms
> - can't run on carrot juice, diet pepsi, or metamucil
> ...

There is probably a long list of *why*, including the types of locks required to make schema modifications. But I suspect *why* isn't the thing that's important here, because answering that question isn't going to change the problem or help you avoid needing to use a workaround.